# Highlight a cell in a Google spreadsheet if the value already exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am attempting to use conditional formatting in a Google Spreadsheet so that if I type a zip code that is already in a column it will highlight that cell.

Because I'm not sure how to do it all within the same column, I created two columns in this spreadsheet so you can see my issue.  Column C has the list of all zip codes in the spreadsheet.  When I type the same zip codes into column B to test, some highlight like they are supposed to and others don't do anything.  I am using this custom conditional formatting formula:  `=match(B1,C:C,0)>0`

Any ideas why it works sometimes and not others?

Spreadsheet is located [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G1HHzHS-vayp0z8SLn-5I-z_CIbgibH_mgA7517HZek/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a list of 10,000 zipcodes in Column A. 
You are typing a new zipcode in Cell B1 and you want to see if this zipcode already exists and where these records are located. The following steps will do this for you:

Select cell B1. 
Go to Format > Conditional Formatting > Add new Rule...> Format Cells if..> Custom Formula and then enter,

```
=if(countif(A:A, B1)>0,1,0)
```

Select column A. 
Go to Format > Conditional Formatting > Add new Rule...> Format Cells if..> Custom Formula and then enter

```
=if(countif($B$1,A1)=1,1,0)
```

Don't forget to change the formatting style in both parts!

You can do it all in one column. if you are just adding cells at the **end** of  column A and want to avoid duplicates, just select column A, repeat the above steps and add this formula instead:

```
=if(A1=INDEX( FILTER( A:A , NOT( ISBLANK( A:A ) ) ) , ROWS( FILTER( A:A , NOT( ISBLANK( A:A ) ) ) ) ),1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks rkdn.  I tried the all in one column thing but it didnt work when I added a zip code that was already there.  Nothing highlighted.  It looks like it just highlighted all the duplicate data when I first applied the rule.

Comment: Hi Mike, just edited the formula. The all in one column works now, if you are always adding cells at the end of the column. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks again.  When I input zip codes into column B it only highlights certain ones.  I can't figure out why only some add and not others.  Very confusing!  Any ideas?